# wrong spark plug in slow plower - stuck cylinder?

Tags: small-engine

I used a wrong spark plug for my Murray 8HP snow plower. When I pulled the string to start the plower it got stuck. I am afraid it might have damaged the cylinder. Appreciate any suggestions to safely get it out and fix the plower. Thanks

Comment: If you pull out the sparkplug, does it turn over?

Comment: I am not able to remove the spark plug. I did apply good amount of force, I want to make sure I can apply more force without causing any further damage. It is not wrong thread as the spark plug (brand new) went in smoothly.

Comment: If it installed easily, you should be able to take it out without issue. You may just need to apply a little more torque to get it out. The reason why you need to do this is to see if the ground strap is displaced as well as if the piston moved freely in the bore once the plug is out.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Is there any risk forcing it out ? Could it have jammed / will jam any internal parts ? The spark plug I used (ie the wrong one) is longer than the original (something I noticed later).